# Attempting to Merge data and sum up the similar items. After a Filter/Sort within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Currently working on a project where im trying to Filter out and Sort out data from one list based on a dropdown menu.  When the data gets pulled from the other list into a better readable format, it brings along some duplicate item names due to being listed seperately based on SKUS, is there any way i can SUM the total qunatities together, and have just 1 name within that list via Functions?

my current function is

```
=SORT(FILTER('Month of Detailed Manifest Report'!B2:D, 'Month of Detailed Manifest Report'!A2:A = A3, 'Month of Detailed Manifest Report'!B2:B <> "SAMPLES"),1,True)
```

Brings my data up like this.

[You can see how it adds Duplicate Data Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Ban.png)

Just trying to get it so it merges the similar names and adds the Qty's together so i can get a better accurate data pull of information.

Comment: This type of formula (which will probably be as using QUERY) is much easier to write around actual data. Consider sharing a link to a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Like other user said, consider adding link to a public google sheet with some sample data. This will help people quickly understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment to your original post. That said, just eyeing it here and without the ability to test it, you can try this formula:

`=QUERY({'Month of Detailed Manifest Report'!A2:D},,"Select Col2, Col3, SUM(Col4) WHERE Col1 = '"&A3&"' AND Col2 <> 'SAMPLES' GROUP BY Col2, Col3 LABEL SUM(Col4) '' ORDER BY Col2")`

In theory, that should work.

If not, as I invited in my previous comment, share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet.